# How to get HTML Purifier to remove content from disallowed tags?

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm using this code to configure HTML Purifier:

```
$config   = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'div,p,ol,ul,li,br'); // only allow these tags
$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
```

What I've found is that while HTMLPurifier does strip tags such as `style` and `table`, the content inside of these tags is still included in the purified output.

How can I get HTML Purifier to not return content in tags that are not allowed?

EDIT:

I found the [Core.HiddenElements](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.HiddenElements) setting, which makes it seem like the contents on the `style` tag should not be shown in the output, but with my configuration they are.

I tried adding the following to my code, but it didn't make any difference (the contents of `style` tags are still shown):

```
$config->set('Core.HiddenElements', array (
    'script' => true,
    'style' => true,
    'table' => true
));
```

Comment: I tried the configuration you have used here and this did work for me. Do you have something else in your config? Which version of htmlpurifier do you use?